# ¿hay alguna manera de mandar el email del que paga con paypal en php?

Tags: php, paypal

¿hay alguna manera de mandar el email del que paga con paypal, de manera que la pueda recibir en la pagina `"notify_url"` en `$_POST?` Se que por defecto se manda la variable `$_POST['payer_email']` pero en caso de que el cliente pague con otro email en paypal distinto del que esta registrado en mi pagina (ya que puede tener mas de una cuenta en paypal) el email que tengo registrado en la base de datos no coincidira con el `$_POST['payer_email']`, y no podre sacar los datos de nombre y apellidos del cliente (no se si me explico). Entonces queria saber si hay alguna manera de mandar el email de forma personalizada desde el formulario de paypal:
gracias por adelantado.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Paypal Integration Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form class="paypal" action="payments.php" method="post" id="paypal_form">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">

    <?php
    for($i=1;$i<3;$i++)
    {
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='quantity_".$i."' value='1'/>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_name_".$i."' value='articulo".$i."'/>");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='item_number_".$i."' value='".$i."' />");
    echo("<input type='hidden' name='amount_".$i."' value='0.2' />");
    }

    ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Payment"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No deberías basarte en el correo electrónico para identificar al cliente, sino el número de orden (pedido o factura) que es de donde vas a tomar todos los datos necesarios: cliente, fecha, importe, fecha de pago, forma de pago, etc.

Comment: ya pero asi habria un problema si el cliente paga con una cuenta de paypal de su madre por ejemplo. No se por donde tirar.

Comment: 1. Guardas el pedido, asociando al cliente (por ID, correo electrónico o lo que prefieras) 2. Inicias el proceso del pago incluyendo el número de pedido 3. Al completar el pago, buscas los datos del cliente desde el pedido y de ahí tomas su dirección para enviar el correo

Comment: vale, y como puedo establecer el email del comprador cuando se carga la pagina de paypal.

Comment: No necesitas hacerlo, porque deberías registrar los datos del usuario en tu base de datos, incluyendo el correo electrónico a donde le enviarás la confirmación del pedido, independientemente de la cuenta que haya usado para pagar en Paypal.